# not setting minDate in bootstrap DateTimePicker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to set mindate of date2 as per date1 selected date.What's wrong on this code? It is not setting mindate to date2.

```
  $('#date1').datetimepicker({
           pickTime:false
        }).on('dp.change', function (e) {
            var date = new Date(e.date.valueOf());
            $('#date2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(date);
        });
        $('#date2').datetimepicker({
            pickTime:false
        });

    });
```

Comment: Which datetimepicker are you using? [tarruda](https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) or [eonasdan](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in your code,

I think your problem in the version of bootstrap you are using.

Try **setMinDate** instead on **minDate**

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/mastersmind/pen/ZKJRWN)

```
 $('#date1').datetimepicker({
    pickTime:false
  });
  $('#date2').datetimepicker({
    pickTime:false,
    useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
  });
  $("#date1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    var date = new Date(e.date.valueOf());
    $('#date2').data("DateTimePicker").setMinDate(date);
  });
```

[Linked Pickers example](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers)

**Note:**

On older versions of Bootstrap datetimepicker (less than v4), use .setMinDate and .setMaxDate